# how can we iterate an object or json in aura?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura

Aura:iteration is only for Arrays / list . If I have json or some kind of JS object to be iterated (like ng-repeat) how do I do it?

Answer (score 2):

In your component's js controller, iterate through the properties and put them in an array.

Then use that array on aura:iteration.

I have an example here (github) that iterates all the fields on a generic sobject:  https://github.com/mshanemc/soql2list/tree/master/src/aura/AllFieldDisplayer

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own aura:iteration that supports this. If you want to just use aura:iteration, you'll need to format the data into an array.